# Bind Value in ng-model through ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to fetch value in my ng-model when checkbox is selected or not.

```
config.previewData[0] = {"Country":"Hong Kong","Level":0,"TonerQty":23166}
```

my html code like

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in config.previewData[0]">

    <label class="checkbox" for="{{$index}}">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="config.Selectedkey[$index]" name="group" id="{{$index}}" />
        {{key}}
    </label>
</div>
```

but in `config.Selectedkey[$index]` nothing is bind when i click on check box.

Comment: What is meant by  'ng-model="config.Selectedkey[$index]"' ?

Comment: update with your sample json data

Comment: @dkc007 so solved....next time please provide appropriate data so that you will get your answer quickly

Comment: @Sa E Chowdary are you able to get data in ng-model for selected or not selected value data?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/gCMo8GmPrqQqOHH6BW4W?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when you use ng-repeat, it creates it own scope with in the repeat. So, when you want to access the parent scope / use the model which is inside the repeat, you need to use controller as syntax / use $parent.

I changed it to use ControllerAs syntax and it started working.

More about [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```js
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.previewData = [{
    "Country": "Australia",
    "TonerQty": 4,
    "TonerQty1": 720
  }, {
    "Country": "Australia",
    "TonerQty": 1,
    "TonerQty1": 20839
  }, {
    "Country": "Australia",
    "TonerQty": 3,
    "TonerQty1": 639
  }, {
    "Country": "Australia",
    "TonerQty": 12,
    "TonerQty1": 36
  }, {
    "Country": "Australia",
    "TonerQty": 0,
    "TonerQty1": 0
  }, {
    "Country": "Australia",
    "TonerQty": 6,
    "TonerQty1": 396
  }, {
    "Country": "Australia",
    "TonerQty": 8,
    "TonerQty1": 24
  }, {
    "Country": "Australia",
    "TonerQty": 5,
    "TonerQty1": 495
  }, {
    "Country": "Australia",
    "TonerQty": 10,
    "TonerQty1": 180
  }, {
    "Country": "Australia",
    "TonerQty": 2,
    "TonerQty1": 1452
  }];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mc">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in previewData[0]">

      <label class="checkbox" for="{{$index}}">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mc.Selectedkey[$index]" name="group" id="{{$index}}" />{{key}}
      </label>
    </div>
    {{mc.Selectedkey}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your JSON as

```
config.previewData[0] = {"Country":"Hong Kong",
                         "Level":0,
                         "TonerQty":23166, 
                         "Selectedkey": false}
```

Your JSON data does not contain a key called `Selectedkey` thats why you cant read the model value.

Also replace the template as

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in config.previewData">
    <label class="checkbox" for="{{$index}}">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="config.Selectedkey[$index]" name="group" id="{{$index}}" />
        {{key}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Because you are looping through config.previewData not config.previewData[0]

Please find the sample code attached.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestApp">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('TestApp', []);

        myApp.controller('TestAppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.previewData = '[{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":4,"TonerQty1":720,"Selectedkey":false},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":1,"TonerQty1":20839,"Selectedkey":false},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":3,"TonerQty1":639,"Selectedkey":false},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":12,"TonerQty1":36,"Selectedkey":false},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":0,"TonerQty1":0,"Selectedkey":false},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":6,"TonerQty1":396,"Selectedkey":false},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":8,"TonerQty1":24,"Selectedkey":false},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":5,"TonerQty1":495,"Selectedkey":false},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":10,"TonerQty1":180,"Selectedkey":false},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":2,"TonerQty1":1452,"Selectedkey":false}]';

            $scope.previewData = JSON.parse($scope.previewData);
        }]);
    </script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="TestAppCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in previewData">

        <label class="checkbox" for="{{$index}}">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Selectedkey" name="group" id="{{$index}}" /> {{key}} - {{Selectedkey}}
        </label>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: my json data like "[{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":4,"TonerQty1":720},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":1,"TonerQty1":20839},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":3,"TonerQty1":639},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":12,"TonerQty1":36},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":0,"TonerQty1":0},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":6,"TonerQty1":396},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":8,"TonerQty1":24},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":5,"TonerQty1":495},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":10,"TonerQty1":180},{"Country":"Australia","TonerQty":2,"TonerQty1":1452}]"

Comment: and its not fixed data it should be dynamic.

Comment: then you need to add a Selectedkey parameter to your JSON data, either from UI or from the response send from server. Because you are setting the modal value to Selectedkey but that's not present in your JSON.

Comment: please check my plnkr i want to display Country,TonerQty and TonerQty1 as a checkbox thats why i write previewData[0]